# bool __cdecl func(void) already defined in func.obj

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm getting

```
error LNK2005: "bool __cdecl hasLogin(void)" (?hasLogin@@YA_NXZ) already defined in B.obj
```

error. `func` is declared in `B.cpp` file, and it's called from `A.cpp` file. `B.cpp` is included in `A.cpp`. Google says that it's not good to include `cpp` in antother `cpp`. If I copy/paste `func` in `A.cpp` there's no problem. How to solve tsis problem correctly?

**PS** I'm new to c++, so forgive if the question is dump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should generally declare your classes/functions in .h (header) files, and implement them in .cpp files. It's also usually a good idea to put [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your .h files so including them multiple times is not a problem. That way your .cpp files can include any .h file without causing any conflicts.

An example; test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

class test {
    public:
        void bop();
}

bool hasLogin();

#endif
```

and the corresponding .cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

void test::bop() {
    std::cout << "bop" << std::endl;
}

bool hasLogin() {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a header file named `B.h` and add the following function declaration:

```
#ifndef _B_HEADER_
#define _B_HEADER_

bool hasLogin(void);

#endif
```

Instead of `#include "B.cpp"` in `A.cpp` use `#include "B.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

write #pragma once in the .cpp//.h where the error is coming, sometimes it avoids the error.